# Unable to extract data after xsl:node-set

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have simplified the following piece of XSL to illustrate my problem better. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  >
  <xsl:output method="xml"  doctype-public="..." doctype-system="..." indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="tmpTotal">
    <root>
      <items>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
      </items>
    </root>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="exsl:node-set($tmpTotal)"/>
  All values:<xsl:copy-of select="($myTotal)/*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="($myTotal)/items/item">
    Item value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  Item count:<xsl:value-of select="count(($myTotal)/items/item)"/>
  Item total:<xsl:value-of select="sum(($myTotal)/items/item)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that the values are in the node  as the xsl:copy-of select works. However, when  I try and obtain any other values (including the Item value, Item count and Item total), I'm not getting any values. Can anyone please help me with this problem? I've spent almost a day on it and can't see why I'm not getting any values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the `root` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl exsl xsl">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="tmpTotal">
    <root>
      <items>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
      </items>
    </root>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="exsl:node-set($tmpTotal)"/>
  All values:<xsl:copy-of select="($myTotal)/*"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="($myTotal)/root/items/item">
    Item value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
    Item count:<xsl:value-of select="count(($myTotal)/root/items/item)"/>
    Item total:<xsl:value-of select="sum(($myTotal)/root/items/item)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs...

```
  All values:<root><items><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item><item>4</item></items></root>
    Item value:1
    Item value:2
    Item value:3
    Item value:4
    Item count:4
    Item total:10
```